# Obtain card_nonce from Square without HTML form / iframe

Tags: square-connect

Square uses the JSON key `card_nonce` is a hashed or "tokenized" temporary string used in place of the credit card number. I don't mind this approach (too much) however the demonstration code uses an HTML form with iframes which are incompatible with my software.

How do I request a `card_nonce` from Square without having to inject any of Square's HTML on to my page / form?

I am fine with either a server cURL request or a cross-site Access-Control JavaScript request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. At this time you must use the card form to collect buyer card details and generate a card nonce, there isn't a nonce generating URL or endpoint.

Comment: In that case how do I style the `iframe` "forms" to match client themes? At bare minimal I need to change the `background-color`, `border`, `color`, `height` and `font-size` properties.

Comment: Sure! Try taking a look at the [documentation for styling the iframes](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/adding-payment-form#stylinginputinteriors)

Comment: Awesome! While I dislike not having a generator this compromise looks acceptable enough. Thank you!